# Missed Facetime calls in and out but nobody initiated them

Tags: ios, facetime

Why is my iPhone 4S giving me spam missed facetime messages on calls I or my friend have not initiated?

Over the last week, I have been receiving missed facetime calls from a friend that doesn't connect. My phone gives a bit of a ring and then gives the message "Missed Facetime call". I texted to tell her that I had received them and she told me she hadn't done that and had in fact received two or three from me. Just this morning my friend said her husband had a missed a Facetime call from me. My phone was not in my pocket or purse but laying on a table when these events happened.

Comment: I have the same issue. My brother's MacBook seems to be calling me twice a day for the last few days now, even though he's not using it.